# The case at line 42 keeps falling through to the case at line 49

Tags: c++, switch-statement

Answer the first 3 questions with n-y-n. That last statement should have stopped but instead goes to the next question instead.

Please ignore the rest if you want. If there are any mistakes, please tell me.

I'm currently taking a programming class for the first time so be gentle with me

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    //Tattoo Decision

    char ans;



    cout <<"This program will help you determine whether you should get a tattoo or not?";
    cout <<"\nPlease answer the questions with either y (yes) or n (no)";
    cout <<"\n\n\nAre you Drunk?: ";
    cin >>ans;

    switch (ans) //finished
    {
        case 'y':
            {
                cout <<"\n\nWell, for obvious reasons, Don't get a tattoo'";
                break;
            }
        case 'n':
        {
            cout <<"\n\nAre your friends egging on you?: ";
            cin>>ans;
            switch(ans)//finished
            {
                case 'y':
                    {
                        cout <<"\n\nAre they laughing?: ";
                        cin >>ans;
                        switch(ans)//finished
                        {
                            case 'y':   
                                {
                                    cout<<"\n\nDon't get a tattoo";
                                    break;
                                }
                            case'n':
                            {
                                cout<<"\n\nLaughing or not, Don't get a tattoo";
                                break;
                            }   
                        }
                    }
                case'n':
                {
                    cout<<"\n\nDoes the tattoo have a special meaning to you?: ";
                    cin>>ans;
                    switch(ans)//finished
                    {
                        case'y':
                            {
                                cout<<"\n\nIs it a name?: ";
                                cin>>ans;
                                switch(ans)//unfinished
                                {
                                    case'y':
                                        {
                                            cout<<"\n\nIs it your significant other?: ";
                                            cin>>ans;
                                            switch(ans)//unfinished
                                            {
                                                case'y':
                                                    {
                                                        cout<<"\n\nDon't fucking get that tattoo'";
                                                        break;
                                                    }
                                            }
                                        }
                                }
                            }
                        case'n':
                        {
                            cout<<"\n\nThen why are you getting a tattoo for? Don't get one";
                            break;
                            }   
                    }
                }   
            }
        }   
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Line numbers are not shown so I don't think they are useful, perhaps you could add the actual output and the expected output to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing a `break`, try adding as below:

```
int main()
{
   //Tattoo Decision
   char ans;

   cout <<"This program will help you determine whether you should get a tattoo or not?";
   cout <<"\nPlease answer the questions with either y (yes) or n (no)";
   cout <<"\n\n\nAre you Drunk?: ";
   cin >>ans;

switch (ans) //finished
{
    case 'y':
        {
            cout <<"\n\nWell, for obvious reasons, Don't get a tattoo'";
            break;
        }
    case 'n':
    {
        cout <<"\n\nAre your friends egging on you?: ";
        cin>>ans;
        switch(ans)//finished
        {
            case 'y':
                {
                    cout <<"\n\nAre they laughing?: ";
                    cin >>ans;
                    switch(ans)//finished
                    {
                        case 'y':   
                            {
                                cout<<"\n\nDon't get a tattoo";
                                break;
                            }
                        case'n':
                        {
                            cout<<"\n\nLaughing or not, Don't get a tattoo";
                            break;
                        }   
                    }
                    break; // <---------- *****
                }
            case'n':
            {
                cout<<"\n\nDoes the tattoo have a special meaning to you?: ";
                cin>>ans;
                switch(ans)//finished
                {
                    case'y':
                        {
                            cout<<"\n\nIs it a name?: ";
                            cin>>ans;
                            switch(ans)//unfinished
                            {
                                case'y':
                                    {
                                        cout<<"\n\nIs it your significant other?: ";
                                        cin>>ans;
                                        switch(ans)//unfinished
                                        {
                                            case'y':
                                                {
                                                    cout<<"\n\nDon't get that tattoo'";
                                                    break;
                                                }
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
                            break; //<--------- *****
                        }
                    case'n':
                    {
                        cout<<"\n\nThen why are you getting a tattoo for? Don't get one";
                        break;
                        }   
                }
            }   
        }
    }   
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: OH MY GOD. thank you. Sorry to waste your time on this insignificant problem but I really do thank you.